# Prove that $(mn)!$ is divisible by $(n!)\cdot(m!)^n$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factorial

> Let $m$ be a positive integer and $n$ a nonnegative integer. **Prove that**
>
> $$(n!)\cdot(m!)^n|(mn)!$$

I can prove it using [Legendre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula), but I have to use the lemma that

$$ \dfrac{\displaystyle\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)!}{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^na_i!} \in \mathbb{N} $$

I believe that it can be proved using the lemma, since [in this answer of Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/division-of-factorials?lq=1) he has mentioned so at the end of his answer.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: That looks like a multinomial coefficient (which you probably already know).

Comment: @martycohen: $\frac{(mn)!}{(m!)^n}$ is a multinomial coefficient. That it is divisible by $n!$ is not as immediately obvious (to me, at least).

Answer (score 20):

Consider you have $mn$ balls with $n$ different colors and $m$ balls of each color. The number of possible arrangements is $$(mn)!\over (m!)^n$$.

However each arrangement has $n!$ "symmetric arrangements", that is, if we exchange color between whole groups we obtain a symmetric arrangement. I.E. for example if we have three color R,G,B, then $RGRBGB$ and $GRGBRB$ are symmetric arrangement by exchanging colors $R$ and $G$.

Thus $(mn)!\over (m!)^n$ is a multiple of $n!$.

Comment: Where does this use OP's lemma?

Comment: The lemma is the same thing as the possible arrangement of $mn$ balls by letting $a_i=m$ for all $i$. But in order to prove the resulting integer is a multiple of $n!$ one needs to consider symmetric arrangements as well.

Comment: @cr001:  I have some doubts about the validity of your arguments. I think in the current situation a *combinatorial proof* should provide a *bijective mapping* to a subset of the whole set and the size of the whole set should be an integral multiple of this subset. But the symmetry argument with recoloring the objects is a kind of *reusage* of already considered objects, so that no longer a bijection to a subset is given.

Answer (score 15):

Taken from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1634624/13854):
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(m(n+1))!}{(m!)^{n+1}(n+1)!}
&=\frac{(mn)!}{(m!)^nn!}\frac{(mn+1)(mn+2)\cdots(mn+m)}{m!(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{(mn)!}{(m!)^nn!}\frac{(mn+1)(mn+2)\cdots(mn+m-1)}{(m-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(mn)!}{(m!)^nn!}\binom{m(n+1)-1}{m-1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Inductively, from $(1)$ we get the formula
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{(mn)!}{(m!)^nn!}=\prod_{k=1}^n\binom{mk-1}{m-1}}\tag{2}
$$

---

By the Lemma,
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{mk-1}{m-1}
&=\frac{(mk-1)!}{(m-1)!(mk-m)!}\\
&\in\mathbb{N}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(2)$ is a product of integers, and so, an integer.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 7):

Let $a,b$ be non-negative integers. Since ${b+a\choose a}=\frac{(b+a)!}{a!\;b!}$ is an integer, we know that 
$$a!\;|\;(b+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(b+a)={b+a\choose a}\;/\;b! \tag{*}$$

Now we use induction on $n$ to solve the original problem.

For $n=0$, the statement is trivially true. Suppose it holds for $n-1$ where $n \ge 1$. Then we have

$$\begin{align}
n! \cdot (m!)^n &= n\cdot m!\cdot\left((n-1)!\cdot(m!)^{n-1}\right)\\
&\stackrel{hyp.}|n\cdot m! * (mn - m)!\\
&=n\cdot m!\cdot(mn)!\;/\;\left((mn-m+1)\ldots(mn)\right)\\
&=(m-1)!\cdot(mn)!\;/\;\left((mn-m+1)\ldots(mn-1)\right)\\
&\stackrel{(*)}|(mn)!
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

**Using the Lemma,** it can be seen that $\dbinom{m}{r}$ is a positive integer, since,

$\dbinom{m}{n} = \dfrac{(m)!}{n!(m-n)!}$

Now, for positive integers $r$ and $m$, consider, the quantity

$$\dfrac{1}{r} \dbinom{rm}{m}$$

Since $\displaystyle \dbinom{m}{r} = \dfrac{m}{r} \dbinom{m-1}{r-1}$,

$$\implies \dfrac{1}{r} \dbinom{rm}{m} = \dbinom{rm-1}{m-1} \tag{1}$$

Thus, by $(1)$,

$\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{r}\dbinom{rm}{m} \in \mathbb{N} $

Let $\displaystyle \text{P} = \prod_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{r} \dbinom{rm}{m}$

$\displaystyle = \prod_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{(rm)!}{[(r-1)m!](m!)r}$

$\displaystyle = \dfrac{1}{n! (m!)^n} \prod_{r=1}^{n} \dfrac{(rm)!}{((r-1)m!)} \tag{*} $

Note that $(*)$ telescopes, thus,

$\displaystyle \text{P} = \dfrac{(mn)!}{(m!)^n n!}$

But, since $\text{P}$ is a product of positive integers, it is itself a positive integer.

$$\displaystyle \implies \dfrac{(mn)!}{(m!)^n n!} \in \mathbb{N} \qquad \square$$

Comment: There was a similar problem in IIT-JEE. You can also solve combinatorially i.e. by taking arrangements.

Comment: The OP has specifically asked for a proof that uses the Lemma. Hence, I solved it this way.

Answer (score 5):

In fact this follows from Lagrange's Theorem: the wreath product $S_m\wr S_n$ is a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_{mn}$. One may view $S_m\wr S_n$ as the set of permutations which preserve the set partition $\{\{1,\cdots,m\},\{m+1,\cdots,2m\},\cdots,\{(n-1)m+1,\cdots,nm\}\}$. If we call the parts of this partition $X_1,\cdots,X_n$, then choosing an element of the stabilizer amounts to choosing a permutation $\sigma:\{1,\cdots,n\}\to\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and then for each $1\le i\le n$ choosing a bijection $X_i\to X_{\sigma(i)}$, so there are $n! m!^n$ elements in the stabilizer.

Answer (score 4):

> We organise the $m\cdot n$ factors of $(mn)!$ into $n$ blocks of size $m$
>   \begin{align*}
>   ((j-1)&m+1)((j-1)m+2)\cdots((j-1)m+m)\tag{1}\\
>   &=((j-1)m+1)((j-1)m+2)\cdots(jm-1)(jm)\qquad 1\leq j \leq n \\
>   \end{align*}
>
> Since for $0\leq m \leq k$ 
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{k}{m}&=\frac{k!}{m!(k-m)!}\\
> &=\frac{(k-m+1)\cdot(k-m+2)\cdots(k-1)\cdot k}{m!}\in\mathbb{N}
> \end{align*}
>   the product of $m$ consecutive integers $\geq 1$ is divided by $m!$. From (1) we conclude that for $1\leq j\leq n$
>   \begin{align*}
>   j( m!)\left|((j-1)m+1)((j-1)m+2)\cdots(jm-1)(jm)\right.\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}
>   since $jm!=(jm)(m-1)!$ and $(m-1)!$ divides the product \begin{align*}
> \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(((j-1)m+k)\qquad\qquad 1\leq j \leq n
> \end{align*}
>    of the $m-1$ consecutive numbers $(j-1)m+k, (k=1,\ldots,m-1)$.

$$ $$

> We conclude:
>
> \begin{align*}
>  n!(m!)^n&=\left(\prod_{j=1}^nj\right)\left(\prod_{j=1}^nm!\right)\\
>  &=\prod_{j=1}^n(m-1)!(mj)\\
>  &\left|\ \prod_{j=1}^n((j-1)m+1)((j-1)m+2)\cdots(jm-1)(jm)\right.\tag{3}\\
>   &=(nm)!\\
>   \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use the divisibility property (2)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you misinterpreded Qiaochu's words and that what he called "basic lemma" is [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29).

Indeed, think $\{1,\dots,mn\}$ as the disjoint union of $n$ blocks of size $m$ in the obvious way. Then $K:=S_m\times\cdots\times S_m$ ($n$ times) is a subgroup of $S_{mn}$,
where the $k$-th factor consists of the permutations of the $k$-th block $\{(k-1)m+1,\dots,km\}$. So $K$ consists of permutations acting on each block separately.

On the other hand, consider the subgroup $L$ of $S_{mn}$ consisting of the permutations of the blocks, leaving the elements of each block in the same order. For instance, the cyclic permutation $\sigma$ of the blocks given by
$\sigma((k-1)m+j):=km+j$ if $1\le k<n$ and $1\le j\le m$,
and $\sigma((n-1)m+j):=j$ (for $k=n$), is an element of $L$.

Now, $L$ is patently isomorphic to $S_n$ and normalizes $K$, meaning that
$\tau K\tau^{-1}=K$ for all $\tau\in L$. Also, $K\cap L=\{\operatorname{id}\}$. From this it follows easily (why?) that $KL$ is a subgroup of $S_{mn}$ of order $|K||L|=(m!)^n\cdot n!$, and we are done by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: It is not true that "$\sigma$ commutes with any permutation in $K$"; a permutation in $K$ keeps blocks fixed as sets, but it can permute each block differently. I know what you mean, but it's normalization (that is, $\sigma K \sigma^{-1} = K$), not centralization :)

Comment: Ah, you are right, that's what I meant! Edited

Comment: I realized I misread the question and refined my answer to reflect that...

Comment: Nice -- just perhaps say explicitly what "block" means.

Comment: Done, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A moment's thought convinces us that
$$P_{m, n} \colon = \frac{(m n)!}{(m!)^n \cdot n!}$$
equals the number of partitions of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, m n\}$ into $n$ subsets of size $m$.

Let's see why the formula of @robjohn

$$P_{m,n} =\binom{m n-1}{m-1}\cdot P_{m, n-1}$$

is true. Indeed, map every such partion of $[m n]$ to the subset containing $1$. There are exactly $\binom{m n-1}{m-1}$ such subsets. Now the fiber of each such element has cardinality $P_{m, n-1}$, being a partition of a set of $m(n-1)$ elements into $n-1$ parts of size $m$.

Answer (score 0):

What about using induction? Trivially true for $m = 1$, since $n! (1!)^m | (1n)!$

Assume true for $m = k$, then $n! (k!)^n$ | $((k)!)^n$, *i.e.* there is an integer $\lambda$ *s.t.* $n! (k!)^n$ = $((k)!)^n$.

Then let $k \to k+1$ and seen to be true if true for k.

Comment: Sorry, there is already an answer using induction here and I specifically want an answer that uses the lemma I have stated in my question.