# Proving $(n!)^n | (n^2)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If we can say n is a natural number, then prove that $(n!)^n \mid (n^2)!$. I  want a process involving variables only. Please help me.

Comment: Can any thing be done to prove this using only basic divisibility rules and congruences? I do not understand.

Comment: Can any thing be done to have you edit your questions and include your efforts/workings within the post, and not just post what you want and how you want it?  This site *want*s you to include your own efforts, because it expects you to try on your own; it's okay to get stuck; just show us where your are stuck, and explain why, and what you do not understand at that particular moment.  Do not tell users to prove, do, evaluate, solve; We consider that rude.  You may ***ask***, but don't command.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1634624), we even have $(n!)^{n+1}\mid\left(n^2\right)!$.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an $n\times n$ grid of cells, and you want to fill those cells with $n$ of each number from $1$ to $n$ so that there is one number in each cell, then
$$
\frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^n}
$$
is the number of different ways you can do that, and therefore it has to be an integer.

Different example (which is actually the same example of you look closely): You have $n^2$ people, and you need to divide them into teams: a red team, a blue team, a green team, and so on. There are $n$ different teams, and each team must have $n$ people in them. Then there are $\frac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^2}$ different ways to assign people to these teams.

Comment: what a cool answer!, +1

Comment: Uh could you please answer the question in a more algebraic manner? Could not understand what you want to say

Comment: @PraneshRanjanDas Sorry, I think an algebraic proof will be significantly longer and a lot more difficult to follow. It will involve prime factorisation, and how many times a given prime goes into $n!$ and $(n^2)!$. It has long sums and floor functions all over. A combinatorial proof like this is by far the simplest way. I can try to come up with a different example.

Answer (score 2):

We can consider $(S_n)^n = S_n \times S_n \times \dots \times S_n$ as a subgroup of $S_{n^2}$ Just let the first copy act on the first $n$ elements in an $n^2$ element set, the second copy on the next $n$ elements etc. This gives a faithful action of $(S_n)^n$ on an $n^2$ element set, hence an embedding $(S_n)^n \hookrightarrow S_{n^2}$.

We get $(n!)^n \mid (n^2)!$ by Lagrange's theorem.

---

Edit: This method can be generalized to show that the multinomial coefficient $\displaystyle \frac{(n_1 + \ldots + n_k)!}{n_1! \cdot \ldots \cdot n_k!}$ mentioned in other answers is an integer.

Consider $S_{n_1} \times S_{n_2} \times \dots \times S_{n_k}$ and let this group act on an $n_1 + n_2 + \dots + n_k$ element set by having the first factor act on the first $n_1$ elements, the second on the next $n_2$ elements, etc. giving an embedding $S_{n_1} \times S_{n_2} \times \dots \times S_{n_k} \hookrightarrow S_{n_1 + \ldots + n_k}$. Then the statement follows again by Lagrange's theorem.

---

Edit 2:

With more careful use of group theory, we can even prove a stronger statement.

Consider the semidirect product $S_n \rtimes (S_n)^n$ where $S_n$ acts on $(S_n)^n$ by permuting the different factors (This is also called a wreath product)

We can define an action of  $S_n \rtimes (S_n)^n$ on an $n^2$ set as follows: Partition the $n^2$ set in $n$ subsets of $n$ elements. We let the left factor $S_n$ of $S_n \rtimes (S_n)^n$ act by permuting the $n$ subsets and let each factor of $(S_n)^n$ act on one of the $n$ subsets. These actions interact in the right way to define an action of the semidirect product $S_n \rtimes (S_n)^n$, which is also faithful. We get an embedding  $S_n \rtimes (S_n)^n \hookrightarrow S_{n^2}$ and we get $(n!)^{n+1} \mid (n^2)!$ by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: This answer may be beyond the scope of the OP, but I think it's the best explanation among the answers here of why rather than merely how the relation holds.

Comment: @anomaly the OP asked in the comments for a more "algebraic" solution and this is what came to my mind. I agree that it may not be what he had in mind, though.

Comment: No, I think it's great, and gave it a $+1$. I think the OP was looking for an argument along the lines of reading off the prime powers dividing $(n!)^n$ and $(n^2)!$, but that's not a good way of approaching the problem.

Comment: (+1) The stronger statement was also proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1634624).

Comment: @robjohn perfect, the linked statement generalizes the extensions of both edits. I have added a group-theoretic proof to the linked question

Answer (score 1):

The given value is the multinomial coefficient $\binom{n^2}{n \cdots n}$. It's thus the coefficient of $x_1^n \cdots x_n^n$ in $(x_1 + \cdots + x_n)^{n^2}$, for example, and in particular is an integer.