# How can I prove $(n^2)!$ greater growth than $(n!)^n$

Tags: asymptotics, exponentiation, factorial

I tried take limit n goes to infinity.
Wolfram solved the limit and $(n^2)!$ has greater growth rate but there is not step by step solution.

I think I can simplify $(n!)^n$ to $(n^n)^n$
But how can I prove $(n^2)! > (n^n)^n$

[Wolfram link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20n-%3E%20inf%20%28n%5E2%29%21%2F%28n%21%29%5En)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2642007/290189

Comment: "I think I can simplify $(n!)^n$ to $(n^n)^n$"  No you can't.  Try it for $n=2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)
$$(n^2)!\sim \sqrt{2 \pi } e^{-n^2} n^{2 n^2+1}$$
and
$$(n!)^n\sim (2 \pi n)^{n/2} e^{-n^2} n^{n^2}>e^{-n^2} n^{n^2+n}$$
Therefore $$(n!)^n<(n^2)!;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N},n>1$$

Comment: I downvoted (sorry) - I think this answer is making matters much more complicated than they need to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the terms as
$$(n!)^n = \underbrace{1 \cdot \dotso \cdot 1}_{n\text{ times}} \cdot \underbrace{2 \cdot \dotso \cdot 2}_{n\text{ times}} \cdot \dotso \cdot \underbrace{n \cdot \dotso \cdot n}_{n\text{ times}}$$
and
$$ (n^2)! = \underbrace{(1 \cdot \dotso \cdot n)}_{n \text{ terms}} \cdot \underbrace{((n+1) \cdot \dotso \cdot 2n)}_{n \text{ terms}} \cdot \dotso \cdot \underbrace{((n(n-1)+1) \cdot \dotso \cdot n^2)}_{n \text{ terms}}$$
You can look at the numbers as groups of $n$ numbers. You can see that the second term is always larger.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but please don't encourage people asking duplicate questions, which can be found by the math search engine https://approach0.xyz.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Both $(n^2)!$ and $(n!)^n$ can be written as a product of a bunch of smaller terms. In fact, they can both be written as a product of $n^2$ terms. How do these terms compare to each other?

Comment: How can I convert to smaller terms.I don't know @MCT