# Prove that $(nk)!$ is divisible by $(n!)^k \cdot k!$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

I want to prove that $\forall n, k \in \Bbb{N}^*$ $(nk)!$ is divisible by $(n!)^k \cdot k!$

Any ideas?

#### My attempts:

##### 1.

I failed with attempt to use Mathematical induction like that (for $n$):

$1$: $(1*k)!$ is obviously divisible by $1!^k \cdot k!$ 
$n$: $A \cdot (n!)^k \cdot k! = (nk)!$, where $A \in \Bbb{N}$ 
$n+1$:
$$
B \cdot ((n+1)!)^k \cdot k!=((n+1)k)! \text{, where } B \in \Bbb{N}
$$
$$ 
A \cdot ((n+1)!)^k \cdot k! = A \cdot (n!)^k \cdot k! (n+1)^k = (nk)! \cdot (n+1)^k
$$
And idk if it is possible to achieve something from that, because of this A and B.

##### 2.

Later I tried to proof it in direct way:
$$(n!)^k=\prod_{i \in B}{i^k} \text{ , where } B=[1,n] \cap \Bbb{N}$$
$$(nk)!=\prod_{i \in A}{i} \text{ , where } A=[1,nk] \cap \Bbb{N}$$
And I tried to show that $\forall x \in B$ $\exists A_x \subset A$ with $k$ divisible by $x$ elements, e.g. $A_x=\{i \cdot x: i \in [1,k]\}$, but for proof to be right this subsets should be disjoint: $\bigcap_{x \in B} A_x=0$ but I can't invent such subsets :(. Also tried to divide A with remainders, but I didn't get anything sensible

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to give a combinatorial interpretation of the quotient. It counts something; can you see what?

Comment: In **1.** you tried induction on $n$; what if you do induction on $k$ while keeping $n$ constant?

Comment: There are many dupes of this question though I don't have one off the top of my head.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $(mn)!$ is divisible by $(n!)\cdot(m!)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574830/prove-that-mn-is-divisible-by-n-cdotmn) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(n!)%5E%7Bk%7Dk!%5Cmid%20(nk)!%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1). Note [Show that $(a!)^b b! \mid (ab)!$](/q/3321803) was closed as a duplicate of that question, and there's also the AoPS thread [a nice problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1833742).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction on $k$ (not on $n$), for $n\in\mathbb N$:

For $k=1$, $(n\cdot1)!$ is obviously divisible by $(n!)^1\cdot 1!$.

Assume that $(nk)! = A(n!)^k\cdot k!$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$ and $A\in\mathbb Z$.

Then for $k+1$,

$$\begin{align*}
[n(k+1)]! &= (nk)!\cdot(nk+1)(nk+2)\cdots(nk+n-1)(nk+n)\\
&= \left[A(n!)^k\cdot k!\right] \cdot (nk+1)(nk+2)\cdots(nk+n-1)n(k+1)\\
&= A(n!)^k \cdot \underbrace{(nk+1)(nk+2)\cdots(nk+n-1)}_{(n-1)\text{ consecutive integers, multiple of }(n-1)!}n \cdot (k+1)!\\
&= A'(n!)^{k+1}\cdot (k+1)!
\end{align*}$$

Using the property that [the product of $n-1$ consecutive integers is divisible by $(n-1)!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12065). So the given divisibility statement doesn't hold for $n=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the same thing, but at the end I just somehow didn't realize, that the product of n consecutive integers is divisible by n! and decided that I had reached a dead end :)